# Error al crear un "Step" en Amazon EMR - S3DistCp

Tags: java

Estoy intentando crear un "Step" y juntar muchos archivos pequeños en uno, así puedo separarlo por días. El problema es que estoy intetando ejecutarlo y no me deja.

Ejecutandolo por comando me funciona bien:

```
hadoop distcp s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test
```

Pero luego si ya entro en los comandos "groupBy" o "srcPattern" no me hace nada.

Luego al crear el "Step" en la consola de Amazon EMR, me esta dando todo el rato error. Os indico el archivo

Comando:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXX --steps Name="S3DistCp step",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["spark-submit","--src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/output-files-hive/*","--dest=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/files-hive/test/"]
```

Error:

```
2016-07-13T15:06:27.677Z INFO Ensure step 3 jar file command-runner.jar
2016-07-13T15:06:27.678Z INFO StepRunner: Created Runner for step 3
INFO startExec 'hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* --dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/'
INFO Environment:
  TERM=linux
  CONSOLETYPE=serial
  SHLVL=5
  JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre
  HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=hadoop
  LANGSH_SOURCED=1
  XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
  HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,DRFA
  AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/mon
  UPSTART_JOB=rc
  MAIL=/var/spool/mail/hadoop
  EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/opt/aws/amitools/ec2
  PWD=/
  HOSTNAME=ip-172-31-21-173
  LESS_TERMCAP_se=[0m
  LOGNAME=hadoop
  UPSTART_INSTANCE=
  AWS_PATH=/opt/aws
  LESS_TERMCAP_mb=[01;31m
  _=/etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java
  LESS_TERMCAP_me=[0m
  NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
  LESS_TERMCAP_md=[01;38;5;208m
  runlevel=3
  AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/as
  UPSTART_EVENTS=runlevel
  HISTSIZE=1000
  previous=N
  HADOOP_LOGFILE=syslog
  PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/aws/bin
  EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
  HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK
  LESS_TERMCAP_ue=[0m
  AWS_ELB_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/elb
  RUNLEVEL=3
  USER=hadoop
  HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/tmp
  PREVLEVEL=N
  HOME=/home/hadoop
  HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
  LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  LESS_TERMCAP_us=[04;38;5;111m
INFO redirectOutput to /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/stdout
INFO redirectError to /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/stderr
INFO Working dir /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK
INFO ProcessRunner started child process 7836 :
hadoop    7836  2229  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* --dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/
2016-07-13T15:06:31.724Z INFO HadoopJarStepRunner.Runner: startRun() called for s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK Child Pid: 7836
INFO Synchronously wait child process to complete : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO waitProcessCompletion ended with exit code 1 : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO total process run time: 2 seconds
2016-07-13T15:06:31.991Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-07-13T15:06:31.992Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 1 and took 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

En la nueva versión de amazon emr, no hace falta incluir el archivo jar S3DistCp, con llamarlo en el argumento vale.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXX --steps Name="S3DistCp step V3",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["s3-dist-cp","--src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/","--dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/"]
```